# How can I add claim mapping in wso2is via configuration?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I added in claim-config.xml but i dont see that claim being added in the IS management console.

```
<ClaimURI>http://wso2.org/claims/serialNumber</ClaimURI>
                                <DisplayName>serialNumber</DisplayName>
                                <AttributeID>url</AttributeID>
                                <Description>SerialNumber</Description>
                                <DisplayOrder>3</DisplayOrder>
                                <SupportedByDefault />
                        </Claim>
```

Also i dont want to add the claim mapping from management console. i want to automate this process so need a configuration change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ClaimManagementService admin service of WSO2 Identity Server to do CRUD operations on claims. You can get an idea of available methods by referring to the wsdl of ClaimManagementService. Please refer to [this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Calling+Admin+Services) for more information regarding calling admin services of WSO2 servers.

Comment: Thanks i got the solution after accessing web services api and calling those web services api via curl ,for automation process

Answer (score 2):

WSO2IS reads the `claim-config.xml` file and add those claims when you start the server first time.  After you update the `claim-config.xml`,  It does not read from it.  When server is started first time,  it reads the `claim-config.xml` file add add those in to the database (as there are no any claim configuration in the database).  If claim mapping are dynamically changed and you do not like to configure them from UI, you can automate the web service API that is used to configure the claims.   If claim mappings are not changed,  them you can add all the configures in the `claim-config.xml` in the first start up.

Comment: Thanks @Asela but can you please help me with the API needed to add claim mapping. Also you have mentioned start the server for the first time. What does this First Time means,you mean making the changes and then starting the server will work or just starting the server when the wso2 package is installed?